# How can I add a delay to the collapsible menu in Twenty Eleven?

Tags: navigation, sub-menu, menus

The navigation menu closes *immediately* upon moving the mouse outside of the menu item's area. How can I introduce a delay that will keep it open a second or less to keep visitors from becoming frustrated when trying to navigate to submenu items?

Comment: This is my question, but apparently I used a temporary login to create it so I can't comment (versus this "answer").... I used the suggestion by helgatheviking as a starting point and found a WP plugin (cleverly named "Superfish Menus") that added Superfish effects to my nav menu. However, I get the fade effect but NO delay. I even tried to manually adjust the code for a 10-second delay and it doesn't honor a delay at all. Does anyone know of a reason that the stock WP menu system in 3.5.1 would not allow this delay?

Comment: Please see [help > merge user profiles](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) if you want duplicate accounts merged.

Answer (score 2):

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) is a script that will add a delay to the hover action.  It is used in a lot of themes, for instance I know it is used in the Thematic Theme.  Untested, but I think this is how you'd apply it (based on the docs).

```
function wp88740_enqueue(){
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('hoverintent', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/scripts/hoverIntent.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/scripts/superfish.js' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wp88740_enqueue');

function wp88740_initialize(){ ?>

// initialise Superfish
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#access ul.menu").superfish();
    });

</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head','wp88740_initialize');
```